# Repairing corrupt MS SQL master database - no SQL client access

Tags: sql-server, database

Apologies for any duplication but I feel like I'm falling at the first hurdle.

I have a MS SQL 2005 Server which is refusing to start and for which I don't have a password (including the 'sa' password), apparently because the master database is corrupt (see log). I have found plenty of instructions by Googling the error message (see below) such as [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207003(v=sql.105).aspx) and [this](http://www.sqldbadiaries.com/2010/08/07/how-i-conquered-a-corrupt-database/), but they all seem to involve being able to run SQL commands in the first place.

Running `sqlcmd` and typing `SELECT * FROM sys.configurationsp; (return)` (as per link 1) results in no output. Running `sqlcmd -S DVTEL` (where DVTEL is one of the SQL Server Services found in Configuration Manager) fails with a connection timeout.

**Error message:**

On starting the server from the configuration manager: `Could not start the SQL Server (DVTEL) on Local Computer. For more info, review the system event log.`
Alternatively:

`> NET START MSSQL$DVTEL /F /T3608
The SQL Server (DVTEL) service is starting.
The SQL Server (DVTEL) service could not be started.
A system error has occurred.
System error 1067 has occurred.
The process terminated unexpectedly.`

**Error Log:**

`2015-06-22 09:42:06.78 Server      (c) 2005 Microsoft Corporation.
2015-06-22 09:42:06.78 Server      All rights reserved.
2015-06-22 09:42:06.78 Server      Server process ID is 2896.
2015-06-22 09:42:06.78 Server      Authentication mode is MIXED.
2015-06-22 09:42:06.78 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.2\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG'.
2015-06-22 09:42:06.78 Server      This instance of SQL Server last reported using a process ID of 1340 at 22/06/2015 09:26:16 (local) 22/06/2015 08:26:16 (UTC). This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2015-06-22 09:42:06.78 Server      Registry startup parameters:
2015-06-22 09:42:06.78 Server        -d C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.2\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf
2015-06-22 09:42:06.78 Server        -e C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.2\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG
2015-06-22 09:42:06.78 Server        -l C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.2\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf
2015-06-22 09:42:06.78 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2015-06-22 09:42:06.78 Server      Detected 4 CPUs. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2015-06-22 09:42:06.95 Server      Error: 8313, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2015-06-22 09:42:06.95 Server      Error in mapping SQL Server performance object/counter indexes to object/counter names. SQL Server performance counters are disabled.
2015-06-22 09:42:06.95 Server      Error: 3409, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2015-06-22 09:42:06.95 Server      Performance counter shared memory setup failed with error -1. Reinstall sqlctr.ini for this instance, and ensure that the instance login account has correct registry permissions.
2015-06-22 09:42:06.99 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
2015-06-22 09:42:07.01 Server      Database mirroring has been enabled on this instance of SQL Server.
2015-06-22 09:42:07.01 spid5s      Starting up database 'master'.
2015-06-22 09:42:07.07 spid5s      Error: 9003, Severity: 20, State: 1.
2015-06-22 09:42:07.07 spid5s      The log scan number (288:224:1) passed to log scan in database 'master' is not valid. This error may indicate data corruption or that the log file (.ldf) does not match the data file (.mdf). If this error occurred during replication, re-create the publication. Otherwise, restore from backup if the problem results in a failure during startup. 
2015-06-22 09:42:07.07 spid5s      Cannot recover the master database. SQL Server is unable to run. Restore master from a full backup, repair it, or rebuild it. For more information about how to rebuild the master database, see SQL Server Books Online.`

Comment: In the MSDN article that you linked to, did you run the setup command to rebuild the system databases? If not, you need to do that (first saving off the files for the msdb and model databases). A corrupt master db will prevent the instance from starting at all.

Comment: @BenThul No, because I assumed I would need to extract the existing configuration first, as described in the article. Anyway, I tried running the downloaded executable with those command line options (in the hope it was in some way equivalent to Setup.exe on the installation medium", but nothing happened. I've uninstalled the MSSQL instance now and reinstalled creating the same DB name (since there was nothing very important on it), but now the software I'm trying to install which uses the DB is complaining that it can't install the command line tools even though  they install fine separately

Comment: You need to take regular backups of your system databases, too. In this case, you'd run through the recreation of your system databases as outlined in the MSDN article and then restore master from your last backup. As to extracting the configuration, that's a best effort. That is, you try to do it and if you succeed, great! But in your case, it just wasn't possible, so you move on.